# How to rotate the background image in the container?

Tags: css, background-image, image-rotation

I want to rotate the image which is placed in the button of scrollbar in Chrome. Now I have a CSS with this content:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url(images/arrowup.png);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #ECEEEF;
    border-color: #999;
}
```

I wish to rotate the image without rotating its content.

Comment: I'd like to do this as well. There's an example of something like this happening on iCloud - see how the vault texture rotates dynamically: https://www.icloud.com/

Comment: that looks kinda like a parallax thing.  couldn't really tell from the code though...

Comment: I guess that maybe you no longer need and answer but maybe someone else would be interested.
Here is a link for a tutorial that shows how to do it : [http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/)

Comment: Unfortunately all of the provided solutions do not work in scroll bars. I ended up creating 4 separate pictures.

Comment: See also: [Rotating a background image with CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15170820/1591669)

Answer (score 192):

Very well done and answered here – http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/

```css
#myelement:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(background.png) 0 0 repeat;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

Comment: FYI, containers rotate about their center point, in case you're having trouble getting exactly the transformation you want.

Comment: fyi, it doesn't work for all elements; for example, a `select` can't have a `:before`.

Comment: Also, beware that 200% may not be enough in all cases, i.e. on oblong elements like 10px × 200px.

Comment: Yeah, but this is _not_ rotating the background. This is faking it with an approximation.  If you actually need the background to be rotated this will not help.

Answer (score 35):

Very easy method, you rotate one way, and the contents the other. Requires a square though

```
#element{
    background : url('someImage.jpg');
}
#element:hover{
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
#element:hover >*{
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

## Update 2020, May:

Setting `position: absolute` and then `transform: rotate(45deg)` will provide a background:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: 2px dashed slateBlue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/120/120" />
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

## Original Answer:

In my case, the image size is not so large that I cannot have a rotated copy of it.  So, the image has been rotated with `photoshop`.  An alternative to `photoshop` for rotating images is [online tool too for rotating images](https://convertimage.net/photo-size-editing-tools/online-picture-rotate-tool.asp).  Once rotated, I'm working with the `rotated-image` in the `background` property.

```
div.with-background {
    background-image: url(/img/rotated-image.png);
    background-size:     contain;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
}
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 8):

**CSS:**

```
.reverse {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.rotate {
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-name: yoyo;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes yoyo {
  from { transform: rotate(  0deg); }
  to   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(buttonElement).click(function () {
  $(".arrow").toggleClass("reverse")

  return false
})

$(buttonElement).hover(function () {
  $(".arrow").addClass("rotate")
}, function() {
  $(".arrow").removeClass("rotate")
})
```

*PS: I've found this somewhere else but don't remember the source*

Answer (score 5):

I was looking to do this also. I have a large tile (literally an image of a tile) image which I'd like to rotate by just roughly 15 degrees and have repeated. You can imagine the size of an image which would repeat seamlessly, rendering the 'image editing program' answer useless.

My solution was give the un-rotated (just one copy :) tile image to psuedo :before element - oversize it - repeat it - set the container overflow to hidden - and rotate the generated :before element using css3 transforms. Bosh!

Comment: i can't "imagine the size of an image which would repeat seamlessly" being very big...

Comment: what if you want your base background image to be tilted?

Answer (score 1):

I tried all solutions but none helped, below is what was my problem and how I solved it:

**Problem:** we have an image for desktops with landscape orientation but To show the same image but rotated (portrait) for mobile screens.

**How:** I just rotated the actual image in my assets folder the way I wanted (portrait), and then just used media queries to call that image for my background for mobiles, and that's it.

(this was the easiest and quick solution I did.)

Answer (score -1):

try making a div for the image only and then flipping it with  `transform: scaleY(-1);` or `transform: scaleX(-1);`
if you want to have the navbar in front of the image you can make an overlapping div and set its opacity property to 0;

Answer (score -3):

## Update Dec 2021

Since the original question is
"..rotate the background image .."

The best answer looks to be here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62135576/3446280