# Javascript - Rotating a rectangle before writing to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been having an enormous amount of difficulty getting a set of rectangles to face a certain point on a canvas block. I'm iterating through a set of points, and drawing rectangles, which are supposed to all face a certain point.

First I set up the Radius, Focus point and Rectangle

```
var Angle = Math.PI;

_.each(Points, function(Point) {
var Radius = 10;

var Focus = {
    X: 500,
    Y: 1000
}

var Rect = [
{
    X: (Point.X - Radius/2),
    Y: (Point.Y - Radius/2)
},
{
    X: (Point.X + Radius/2),
    Y: (Point.Y - Radius/2)
},
{
    X: (Point.X + Radius/2),
    Y: (Point.Y + Radius/2)
},
{
    X: (Point.X - Radius/2),
    Y: (Point.Y + Radius/2)
}
];
```

Then, using underscore, I iterate through and used the method I read about on another response.

```
var index = 0;
_.each(Rect, function (V) {
    var dx2 = Focus.X - V.X;
    var dy2 = Focus.Y - V.Y;
    var dx2_ = dx2 * Math.cos(Angle) - dy2 * Math.sin(Angle);
    var dy2_ = dy2 * Math.sin(Angle) + dy2 * Math.cos(Angle);

    V.X = dx2_ + V.X;
    V.Y = dy2_ + V.Y; 

    Rect[index] = V;
    index++;
});
```

Then its all set up in the normal canvas stuff. The context and the fillStyle are defined beforehand.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(Rect[0].X, Rect[0].Y);
ctx.lineTo(Rect[1].X, Rect[1].Y);
ctx.lineTo(Rect[2].X, Rect[2].Y);
ctx.lineTo(Rect[3].X, Rect[3].Y);
ctx.lineTo(Rect[0].X, Rect[0].Y);

ctx.fill();

});
```

These are the initial squares (without the rotation each loop)

Without rotation
[image: Without Rotation]

This is what I get instead (seems like the rectangles are being rotated around the point instead of rotating towards the point)

With angle set to pi
[image: With angle set to pi]

The behavior that I'm trying to get is to have them facing towards the bottom middle. (500,1000) if the canvas is 1000x1000.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nmartin413/cMwTn/7/

I can't for the life of me figure out whats going wrong. If there's anything that stands out to you, please let me know :). Sorry for the long question, but this has really frustrated me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention that. I added some before and after images

Comment: Why not use fillRect to draw a filled rectangle??  http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes

Comment: That was where I started, but there's no way to rotate a rectangle made with fillRect. You can rotate the entire canvas, but not the rectangles themselves. Unless I'm mistaken...

Comment: may be you like css3 solution ? [how-to-rotate-the-background-image-in-the-container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087420/how-to-rotate-the-background-image-in-the-container)

Comment: I also considered this, but I cannot target individual canvas rectangles with css, as they've got no dom representation. I thought about just using div's, but with up to 1000 rectangles, I fear the performance hit

Comment: ok, can you make jsbin/jsfiddle ?

Comment: Sure - here it is. Thanks for looking into this :) http://jsfiddle.net/nmartin413/cMwTn/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to draw the rectangles yourself, use `ctx.rotate(angle);` and `ctx.fillRect(-Radius/2, -Radius/2, width, height);` as it is more simple, and code-wise - much easier to read and manage. To accomplish this rotation, save and redraw  the canvas every time you apply a transformation to a rectangle, using `ctx.save();` and `ctx.restore();`

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Canvas = $('canvas')[0];
    var Focus = {
        X: 500,
        Y: 1000
    };
    var f = Focus;
    var angle = 0;
    var Radius = 10;
    _.each(Points, function($Point) {
        var ctx = Canvas.getContext('2d');
        var x = $Point.X;
        var y = $Point.Y;
        var width = Radius;
        var height = Radius;
        var cx = x - 0.5 * width;
        var cy = y - 0.5 * height;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(x,y);
        var angle = (Math.atan2(f.Y-y,f.X-x));
        ctx.rotate(angle);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ED1B24";
    ctx.fillRect(-Radius/2, -Radius/2, width, height);
        ctx.restore();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mJNas/

Comment: Thanks! I ended up figuring it out mathematically, but your way is far more simple.