# div background and text different behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css

In this fiddle I wish to rotate only background image of div , currently div text `This is div` is also rotated I wish to avoid text rotation.

Code:

```
   .flippy {
    /**/-moz-transform:scale(1,1);-webkit-transform:scale(1,1);
    transform:scale(1,1);
    /**/-webkit-transition:all 600ms ease;-webkit-transition:all 600ms ease;
    transition:all 600ms ease; }
    .flippy[flipped] {
        /**/-moz-transform:scale(-1,1);-webkit-transform:scale(-1,1);
        transform:scale(-1,1); }
#flippy1
{
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color:red;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/simmi_simmi123/sesZv/3/

Comment: Add a wrapper, flip the interior elements back ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/sesZv/12/)). Otherwise you'll have to remove the background from the element, put it in its own element and flip only that element.

Comment: This is the second time you duplicate the same question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087420/

Comment: @Zeta i want to put image and text in same div

Comment: @simmisimmi: Text and image? There is no image in the div with the text. Do you mean text and background image, which is something else?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img.flippy').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('flipped'))
        $(this).removeAttr('flipped');
    else $(this).attr('flipped','flipped');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution, but here's a workaround with z-index

```
<img class="flippy" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"/>
<div class="no-rotate"> My div rotated </div>
<div class="flippy" id="flippy1"> 

</div>


.no-rotate{
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: no this is not what i want ...  i want to use same div for text and images

Comment: Do you want a result like above (but in only 1 div) or do you want a "trick" like @Zeta suggest with a revert flip?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

wrap the text with `p` and style the `p` with following

```
p.notflip{
    /**/-moz-transform:scale(-1,1);-webkit-transform:scale(-1,1);
    transform:scale(-1,1);
}
```

also edit you jquery like this

```
$('.flippy').click(function(){                  
    if ($(this).attr('flipped')){
        $(this).removeAttr('flipped');
        $(this).children('p').removeClass('notflip');}
    else {
        $(this).attr('flipped','flipped');
        $(this).children('p').addClass('notflip');}
});
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/sesZv/19/)

Comment: there in no image inside the 'flippy1' div, you like to add the lorempixel.com image inside the 'flippy1' div?