# CSS: background-image rotate without transform: rotate()

Tags: css

I rotated the block that is given a background-image, I need the image not to be rotated but the block that is given the image to be rotated.

[page link](http://bagrattam.com/stackoverflow/bg-skew/bg-2.html)
What must I do?

Thank you.

**CSS:**

```
   .bg {
        background-image: url("http://bagrattam.com/sss/website/images/other/paint.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: absolute;
        top: -50%;
        left: -10%;
        right: -10%;
        height: 170%;
        z-index: -1;
        transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
```

Comment: You put image in a pseudo element like `::after` and reverse its rotate

Comment: how should I do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate the background image in the container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087420/how-to-rotate-the-background-image-in-the-container)

Comment: I've seen this article, but there is no any solution because they rotated with transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, remove the rotation from the CSS of the `.bg` class and increase its height from `170%` to `225%`:

```
.bg {
    background-image: url(http://bagrattam.com/website/images/other/paint.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: -10%;
    right: -10%;
    height: 225%;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

Then use the `:after` pseudo class to add a rotated overlay over the image which adds the skew effect:

```
.bg:after {
    content: "";
    font-size: 200px;
    background: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -350px;
    transform: rotate(-8deg);
}
```

Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Do you have a working example in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Use a psuedo element, put the image in that and rotate it the other way

```
.bg:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -10%;
  right: -10%;
  height: 170%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(http://bagrattam.com/website/images/other/paint.png') 0 0 repeat;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Don't forget to set the main elements 'overflow:hidden' so it doesn't flow outside.

Comment: `.background:before {

  background-image: url('http://bagrattam.com/website/images/other/paint.png');

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-size: cover;

  content: "";

  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;

  height: 130%;

  top: 0%;

  left: 0%;

  z-index: -1;

  transform: rotate(10deg);

 }`

Comment: So I could not write the code correctly but it was help, thanks.