# How do I create rotating animation for background image within container without rotating entire container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to HTML and CSS and have been stuck on this problem for a while. Ideally I'm looking for a solution that is CSS only, but I can try a JavaScript solution if I need to. My code is probably very badly written so please forgive me.

I am trying to create a rotating banner animation effect for my personal website. I have a container that has a background image of a colour wheel, and I have some divs within this container that hold my logo and a subtitle.

[image: Banner]

The colour wheel image is just a large circle. I am looking to rotate this image without it rotating the whole container.

[image]

I have tried everything from this post but this just rotates the image once where as I would like to rotate the image continuously: [How to rotate the background image in the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087420/how-to-rotate-the-background-image-in-the-container)

I have also tried this, which has the animation aspect but also rotates the whole container: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/rotate-background-image-constantly/251925/3

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
  <section id="banner">
      <div class= "banner-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col text-center">
              <img src="images/BenMillerType.png" class="logo"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <p class="promo-title text-center"></p>
            <p class="promo-subtitle text-center">
              Graphic Design | 3D Design | UI/UX Design
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div id="work"></div>
  </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
#banner {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: #FFFDC4 ;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.banner-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url(/images/ColourWheel.png);
  background-position: center;
  margin:0 !important;
}

.promo-subtitle {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(42, 156, 157) !important;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 250px;
  object-fit:contain;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2 !;
}
```

Comment: Separate out the background image by putting it on a before pseudo element and rotating that rather than rotating the whole thing including the text. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and update your question if you need more help. Please note however that some users might find a constant rotating image disturbing so provide a way to have a more static interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the logo part from the color wheel part so you can access only the part you want to animate...

Once you have done this. You can add an animation to the container you want to rotate..

```css
    #test {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtolD.png');
        background-size:cover;
    }

    @keyframes rotating {
        from{
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to{
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    .rotating {
        animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
    }
```

```html
<div id='test' class='rotating'></div>
```